# How to fix PyImport_Import in C++ (Exception in python35.dll)

Tags: c++, python-3.x, python-embedding

I am trying a really basic "hello world" program, which should embedd a python script in my C++ console application, but it fails at `pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);` with an unspecified exception "Access violation reading location ..."

I was already able to run `PyRun_SimpleFile()` for a python script without definitions and returns, but for my future application I need a python method with returns, so `PyRun_SimpleFile()` is not an option.

My code, based on [this Introduction](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820116/Embedding-Python-program-in-a-C-Cplusplus-code) is:

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule;
    PyObject *pFunc, *pValue;

    pName = PyUnicode_FromString("HelloWorld");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_XDECREF(pName);

    if (pModule)
    {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "getInteger");
        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
        {
            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
            printf_s("C: getInteger() = %ld\n", PyLong_AsLong(pValue));
            Py_XDECREF(pValue);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ERROR: function getInteger()\n");
        }
        Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
    }
    else
    {
        printf_s("ERROR: Module not imported\n");
    }

    Py_XDECREF(pModule);

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

HelloWorld.py (in Debug Location of my VS2015 Solution):

```py
def getInteger():
    print('Python function getInteger() called')
    c = 100*2
    return c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I believe some instructions is lacking in your code, like `Py_Initialize`. I also would use `PyImport_ImportModule` instead of `PyImport_Import`. See this sequence that you could be trying:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_SetPythonHome(L"path/to/python/folder");
    Py_Initialize();
    //PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv); //optional, argv must be wchar_t
    PyObject *pFunc, *pValue;

    pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("HelloWorld");

    if (pModule)
    {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "getInteger");
        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
        {
            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
            printf_s("C: getInteger() = %ld\n", PyLong_AsLong(pValue));
            Py_XDECREF(pValue);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ERROR: function getInteger()\n");
        }
        Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
    }
    else
    {
        printf_s("ERROR: Module not imported\n");
    }

    Py_XDECREF(pModule);

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

If still not working, try adding this after `PyInitialize`:

```
PyRun_SimpleString(
    "import os, sys \n"
    "sys.path.append(os.getcwd()) \n"
);
```

Also after `PyInitialize`, you can check if it's initialized with `Py_IsInitialized`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The missing `Py_Initialize` solved it! But now I'm stuck on a read access violation on Py_Finalize. Any ideas on that too?

Comment: Try not to `Py_XDECREF(pModule)`. Remove this line and see if it stops crashing.

Comment: This did not change it, unfortunately. But I found out that the heap gets corrupted, but I can't really figure out where?

Comment: Since this is unrelated to the original question, I decided to open up a new one. Thanks for your help!